# How to permanently change Cassandra's logging level?

Tags: logs

I'm using `nodetool setlogginglevel` to set logging level of Cassandra, but all the changes would be lost after I restarted the Cassandra process. Is there a way to permanently set its logging level?

Answer (score 1):

Make changes to the **log4j-server.properties** file of Cassandra. This [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_t.html) will help you to set the log levels permanently.